# Magento 2 How to Add a New Column to Orders Grid

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, order-grid

I've added a new column to the table `sales_order` called `export_status`, now I want to add new order grid column with the data from the new `sales_order` column.

I've managed to add column to `the sales_order_grid` table.

```
$installer->getConnection()->addColumn($installer->getTable("sales_order_grid"), "xml_exported", [
     'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
     'comment' => 'XML Exported'
]);
```

How can I now make it actually show in the orders grid with the value from the `sales_order` `export_status` column?

Comment: You may find the answer http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/87012/how-to-add-new-column-to-core-module-of-admin-grid-in-magento2

Comment: I think there is a better way of doing this without having to implement an observer and using events.

Comment: Try the solution [here](http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/159691/50597) This method uses plugin to add columns.

Comment: @AbidMalik Does this need another table to store? I've follow some course and they only use "quote" and "sales_order" table in database. They didn't use the 3rd table, in this case is "affiliate" table.

Comment: @fudu you have to add columns to grid_table; for actual values in database it depends whether you need to add columns to existing tables or create new tables altogether. this tutorial shows adding new table - it all depends on what is your scenario.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

After lots of digging into Magento's core code, I found a solution to my question. Instead of adding a column to the grid via the database, I created  a UI component `sales_order_grid.xml` under `[COMPANY]/[MODULE]/view/adminhtml/ui_component/sales_order_grid.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <columns name="sales_order_columns">
        <column name="export_status" class="[COMPANY]\[MODULE]\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Status">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">XML Exported</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

Then created the UI class under `[COMPANY]/[MODULE]/Ui/Component/Listing/Column/Status.php`

```
<?php
namespace [COMPANY]\[MODULE]\Ui\Component\Listing\Column;

use \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface;
use \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
use \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory;
use \Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column;
use \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder;

class Status extends Column
{
    protected $_orderRepository;
    protected $_searchCriteria;

    public function __construct(
        ContextInterface $context,
        UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory,
        OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository,
        SearchCriteriaBuilder $criteria,
        array $components = [],
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_orderRepository = $orderRepository;
        $this->_searchCriteria  = $criteria;
        parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
    }

    public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
    {
        if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
            foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as & $item) {

                $order  = $this->_orderRepository->get($item["entity_id"]);
                $status = $order->getData("export_status");

                switch ($status) {
                    case "0":
                        $export_status = "No";
                        break;
                    case "1";
                        $export_status = "Yes";
                        break;
                    default:
                        $export_status = "Failed";
                        break;

                }

                // $this->getData('name') returns the name of the column so in this case it would return export_status
                $item[$this->getData('name')] = $export_status;
            }
        }

        return $dataSource;
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked great.  I'm facing an issue where this customization causes the toolbar of the order grid to be rendered after the grid.  Did you experience this issue?

Comment: @Ian I did not have that issue. Which version of magento 2 are you using?

Comment: CE 2.1.1.  I determined the issue.  My module came before Magento_Sales alphabetically.  I added <sequence> with a dependency to Magento_Sales, disabled my module and then re-enabled it.  This corrected the issue.

Comment: Does this work for export options also? In my case exported data had empty values.

Comment: What do you mean export options?

Comment: @AndréFerraz When you export the orders. Also how will the custom filtering will work?

Comment: @MagePsycho what custom filtering?

Comment: @AndréFerraz Imagine the case when you want to filter export_status as: `export_status is null or export_status = 0` when 'XML Exported' = No is selected. How would you filter?

Comment: @MagePsycho I can not understand you sorry. Do you mean sorting on the grid?

Comment: Likewise Magento 1's `filter_condition_callback` where you can add your own custom filter as per field. Please don't say "What do you mean?" this time ;)

Comment: after using this, the filters block became BELOW the table rather than above it

Comment: @Ian , i had the same issue, how did u solve that?

Comment: @Zorox This was a long time ago and I don't remember exactly.  But, I think it was that my module was being loaded in the wrong order.  I added <module name="Magento_Sales" /> to the sequence dependency list in module.xml for my module.  That's not  enough though, you then need to disable your module and then re-enable it so that the config.php gets regenerated with the correct sequence.

Comment: @Ian  thanks.. did all that ... didnt work, i had to rearrange the modules in "config.php" manually to work

Comment: I need to show two fields in sales order grid how can i return it? This one will help for single data only please help me how to pass multiple data to the Sales order grid

Comment: Does anyone know how to make the column label dynamic? I want to label the column differently based on a config setting.

Comment: @DennisvanSchaik just replace the switch statement with ScopeConfigInterface getter function.

Comment: @AndréFerraz I meant the label in the frist row, in this case:
<item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">XML Exported</item>

Comment: @DennisvanSchaik you could do a plugin to the column renderer class or plugin to the translation class  and use the XML title to hook into and do your stuff.

Comment: @AndréFerraz, I got pop up box something went wrong.. after apply commands for this module. want help if you can...

Comment: @DennisvanSchaik It reflect on Customer_order_grid collection in Customer->Order Tab(Customer Information) in admin panel of magento-2.1.Customer_order_grid  is not showing.

Comment: After adding this code filter toolbar got disappeared

Comment: this code is works for me thank you @AndréFerraz

Answer (score 43):

My solution may be a bit more efficient since it follows the native way of adding a column to the grid, and you won't have to load every order displayed on the page to obtain the column data (utilizing the **sales_order_grid** table instead). The above is a great example of how to create a customized renderer though.

**vendor/[vendor]/[package]/view/adminhtml/ui_component/sales_order_grid.xml**

```
<!-- Add the column "my_column" (My Column) to the sales order grid. -->
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
<columns name="sales_order_columns">
    <column name="my_column">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">My Column</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
</columns>
```

Please note that you must enable the column using the drop-down widget above the order grid before it appears.

**vendor/[vendor]/[package]/etc/di.xml**

```
<!-- Sync the column "my_column" between the sales_order and sales_order_grid tables -->
<virtualType name="Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid" type="Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Grid">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="columns" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="my_column" xsi:type="string">sales_order.my_column</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
```

**Sample setup code to add a column to sales_order_grid table (use this in your install/upgrade script). The same code works for the sales_order table by the way.**

```
$setup->getConnection()->addColumn(
        $setup->getTable('sales_order_grid'),
        'my_column',
        [
            'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            'length' => 255,
            'nullable' => true,
            'comment' => 'My Column'
        ]
    );
```

Hope it helps! :-)

Comment: This answer requires that the column is sales_order_grid table, correct?

Comment: @MageParts, when this script will work ?

Comment: worked for me, thanks :3 btw, in that `sales_order_grid.xml` you should close your <listing></listing> tag or it will return an error of xml

Comment: <argument name="columns"> should be replaced with <argument name="columns" xsi:type="array"> in the di:xml file. Otherwise it will return the following error.

Invalid Document
Element 'argument': The type definition is abstract.

Answer (score 7):

The answers here were very helpful, thank you! Here's an answer with some updated material *(usage of `db_schema.xml` vs setup scripts, how to populate column data & clear UI bookmarks)*.

### 1. Create Database Columns

I didn't see any answers here using [`db_schema.xml`](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/declarative-schema/db-schema.html). I'm not sure this feature was implemented when the question was first asked, but it is a much easier method for creating the necessary database columns in the grid tables.

Here's an example `db_schema.xml` for adding the `coupon_code` column to both of the order grid tables:

**`Vendor/Module/etc/db_schema.xml`**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/schema.xsd">
    <!-- Add column to "sales_order_grid" -->
    <table name="sales_order_grid">
        <column xsi:type="varchar" name="coupon_code" nullable="true" length="255" comment="Coupon Code"/>
    </table>
    <!-- Enterprise Edition: Add column to "magento_sales_order_grid_archive" -->
    <table name="magento_sales_order_grid_archive">
        <column xsi:type="varchar" name="coupon_code" nullable="true" length="255" comment="Coupon Code"/>
    </table>
</schema>
```

### 2. Configure Grid Columns in Virtual Classes

The grid columns are defined in a [virtual `Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid` class](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/88dedff640acbaaf8570dab4ee2e46553851b045/app/code/Magento/Sales/etc/di.xml#L488-L540) in the `Magento_Sales` dependency injection (`di.xml`) file. You can study the file to see how to select columns and join data from other tables.

**`Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml`**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <virtualType name="Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="columns" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="coupon_code" xsi:type="string">sales_order.coupon_code</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
    <virtualType name="Magento\SalesArchive\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="columns" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="coupon_code" xsi:type="string">sales_order.coupon_code</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
</config>
```

Enterprise edition users will also have the `Magento_SalesArchive` module. The module's `di.xml` file defines a similar `Magento\SalesArchive\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid` virtual class.

### 3. Add Columns to UI Components

Now we need to add the column to the UI component definition file.

**`Vender/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/sales_order_grid.xml`**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <columns name="sales_order_columns">
        <column name="coupon_code">
            <settings>
                <filter>text</filter>
                <label translate="true">Coupon Code</label>
                <visible>false</visible>
            </settings>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

*Enterprise users: update the archive grid component as well.*

**`Vender/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/sales_archive_order_grid.xml`**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <columns name="sales_order_columns">
        <column name="coupon_code">
            <settings>
                <filter>text</filter>
                <label translate="true">Coupon Code</label>
                <visible>false</visible>
            </settings>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

### 4. Populate Data

The columns should be created in the database, configured to show on the order grids, and new orders should populate the data as expected. *Existing orders* will need another solution to populate missing data.

The [best solution](https://gist.github.com/sivaschenko/ff1e9e8f90f082b8d3e83415aa63082f#file-blog-magento2-sales-order-grid-column-upgrade-script-php) I found was from [this article](https://medium.com/@sivaschenko/magento-2-adding-a-column-to-the-sales-order-grid-fca2f62c0b0c). The solution simply runs a SQL `UPDATE` / `SET` query *(example in patch file below)*.

### 5. Optional: Delete UI Bookmarks

If you find that the column settings are not reflecting on the grid, you may want to delete the `sales_order_grid` entries in the `ui_bookmark` database table *(Refer to example in patch file below)*.

*Enterprise users: refresh the `magento_sales_order_grid_archive` entries as well.*

---

I addressed steps `4` and `5` together with a [patch file](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/declarative-schema/data-patches.html).

`Vendor/Module/Setup/Patch/Data/PopulateGridData.php`

```php
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Setup\Patch\Data;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\DataPatchInterface;
use Magento\Ui\Model\ResourceModel\Bookmark\Collection as BookmarkCollection;

class PopulateGridData implements DataPatchInterface
{
    /**
     * @var BookmarkCollection
     */
    private $bookmarkCollection;

    /**
     * @param BookmarkCollection $bookmarkCollection
     */
    public function __construct(
        BookmarkCollection $bookmarkCollection
    ) {
        $this->bookmarkCollection = $bookmarkCollection;
    }

    /**
     * Populate sales order grid tables
     */
    private function populateSalesOrderGridColumns()
    {
        // Get connection
        $connection = $this->bookmarkCollection->getConnection();

        // Get grid table names
        $gridTables = [
            $connection->getTableName('sales_order_grid'),
            $connection->getTableName('magento_sales_order_grid_archive'),
        ];

        // Loop through grid tables
        foreach ($gridTables as $table) {
            // Build update select
            $select = $connection->select()->join(
                $connection->getTableName('sales_order'),
                sprintf("sales_order.entity_id = %s.entity_id", $table),
                ['netsuite_internal_id', 'coupon_code']
            );

            // Execute SQL query
            $connection->query(
                $connection->updateFromSelect(
                    $select,
                    $table
                )
            );
        }
    }

    /**
     * Refresh UI bookmarks table
     */
    private function deleteOrderGridBookmarks()
    {
        // Get collection and connection
        $connection = $this->bookmarkCollection->getConnection();

        // Get ID's to delete
        $ids = $this->bookmarkCollection->addFieldToFilter('namespace', [
            'in' => ['sales_order_grid', 'sales_archive_order_grid']
        ])->getColumnValues('bookmark_id');

        // Delete
        $connection->delete(
            $this->bookmarkCollection->getMainTable(),
            $connection->quoteInto('bookmark_id IN(?)', $ids)
        );
    }

    /**
     * Delete order grid UI bookmarks
     */
    public function apply()
    {
        $this->populateSalesOrderGridColumns();
        $this->deleteOrderGridBookmarks();
    }

    /**
     * Get aliases (previous names) for the patch.
     *
     * @return string[]
     */
    public function getAliases()
    {
        return [];
    }

    /**
     * Get array of patches that have to be executed prior to this.
     *
     * @return string[]
     */
    public static function getDependencies()
    {
        return [];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**For creating a new column in order grid , I have referred Magento Default Module  vendor/magento/module-customer-balance**

In my case,'custom_column' column already exists in the sales_order table.

I have to show 'custom_column' column in order grid

**Step 1: Add a new Column in sales_order_grid table**

```
        $connection = $installer->getConnection();
        if ($connection->isTableExists('sales_order_grid')) {
            $connection->addColumn(
                $connection->getTableName('sales_order_grid'),
                'custom_column',
                [
                    "type"      =>  Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                    'default'   =>  null,
                    "comment"   =>  'Custom Column'
                ]
            );
    }
```

**Step 2 : di.xml file in app\code[Vendor][NameSpace]\etc\di.xml**

```
 <!-- Adding Columns in sales_order_grid-->
    <virtualType name="Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="columns" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="custom_column" xsi:type="string">sales_order.custom_column</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
    <virtualType name="Magento\SalesArchive\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="columns" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="custom_column" xsi:type="string">sales_order.custom_column</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
```

**Step 3 : Create sales_order_grid.xml layout file under app\code[Vendor][NameSpace]\view\adminhtml\ui_component**

```
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <columns name="sales_order_columns">
        <column name="custom_column">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Custom Column</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

Note: This has been tested in Magento version 2.2.6

Answer (score 0):

> Demo/ExtendedGrid/view/adminhtml/ui_component/sales_order_grid.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <columns name="sales_order_columns">
        <column name="new_column_name" class="Demo\ExtendedGrid\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\NewColumnStatus">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="sortable" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="has_preview" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">New Column Name</item>
              </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

Then Created the UI Class to render it.

> Demo/ExtendedGrid/Ui/Component/Listing/Column/NewColumnStatus.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Demo\ExtendedGrid\Ui\Component\Listing\Column;

/**
 * Class  NewColumnStatus
 */
class NewColumnStatus extends \Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column
{

    /**
     * @var string[]
     */
    protected $statuses;

   /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param ContextInterface $context
     * @param UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory
     * @param CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
     * @param array $components
     * @param array $data
     */
       public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $urlBuilder,
        array $components = [],
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->urlBuilder = $urlBuilder;
         parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
    }


    /**
     * Prepare Data Source
     *
     * @param array $dataSource
     * @return void
     */
    public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
    {
        if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
            foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as &$item) {

           //put  the logic here


            }
        }

        return $dataSource;
   }
}
```

Dont forget to clear cache.

Answer (score -1):

I have created custom module which will add custom attribute in Sales Order entity and then show in admin Sales Order grid.

module.xml file to define the module.
app\code\COMPANY\MODULE\etc\module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="COMPANY_MODULE" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Sales"/>
            <module name="Magento_Quote"/>
            <module name="Magento_Checkout"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

di.xml file in app\code\COMPANY\MODULE\etc\di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <virtualType name="Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid" type="Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Grid">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="columns" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="export_status" xsi:type="string">sales_order.export_status</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
</config>
```

InstallData.php to add custom attribute export_status in database table

app\code\COMPANY\MODULE\Setup\InstallData.php

```
<?php

namespace COMPANY\MODULE\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

/**
 * @codeCoverageIgnore
 */
class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    /**
     * EAV setup factory
     *
     * @var EavSetupFactory
     */
    private $eavSetupFactory;

    /**
     * Init
     *
     * @param EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
     */
    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        /** @var EavSetup $eavSetup */
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.0') < 0){      
            $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
            $salesSetup = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Setup\SalesSetup');
            $salesSetup->addAttribute('order', 'export_status', ['type' =>'varchar']);
            $quoteSetup = $objectManager->create('Magento\Quote\Setup\QuoteSetup'); 
        }
    }
}
```

sales_order_grid.xml to add custom column in Sales Order admin grid.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <columns name="sales_order_columns">
        <column name="export_status">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">XML Exported</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

You can download the full module by clicking on below link 
http://vdcstaging.co.in/download/add-custom-culumn-to-admin-grid.zip