# Magento 2 Add Column To Sales Order Grid Issue

Tags: magento-2.1, grid, sales-order, uicomponent

I am facing layout issue when I added new column in sales order Grid. For some reason **filter and options** are **displaying below grid.**

Please Refer Screenshot

[image]

My Code How I added the column.

**etc/module.xml**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Namespace_Modulename" setup_version="1.0.0"/>
    <sequence>
        <module name="Magento_Sales" />
    </sequence>
</config>
```

**view/adminhtml/ui_component/sales_order_grid.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <columns name="sales_order_columns">
        <column name="my_custom_column">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="sorting" xsi:type="string">desc</item>                    
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">My Custom Column</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

**etc/di.xml**

```
<virtualType name="Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="columns" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="my_custom_column" xsi:type="string">sales_order.my_custom_column</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
```

My column was added but now I am facing this layout issue.

Comment: Probably duplicate of this..https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/134754/magento-2-how-to-add-a-new-column-to-orders-grid

Comment: @arushi I have tried those solution that and my problem was not resolved. And do refer I don't want to know how I can add Column. I am facing issue after adding it.

Comment: I tried your code and it works perfectly fine and as per one of the comment on that post(regarding sequence, if you tried that might be that solves the issue.)

Comment: I have tested it in 2.1.6 and I am facing this issue as shown in screenshot

Comment: @userpk Do you checked that in app/etc/config.php your module is really after Mangeto_Sales module?

Comment: Ya I got to know that for some reason it not coming after Magento_Sales. I tried disabling and re enabling the module still dint work for me. If I manually keep it below then its work fine but thats not the solution :(

Answer (score 2):

please add **etc/di.xml** file in **app/code/Custom/Module/etc/di.xml** and add below code.

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
       <virtualType name="Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid">
         <arguments>
           <argument name="columns" xsi:type="array">
             <item name="my_custom_column" xsi:type="string">sales_order.my_custom_column</item>
           </argument>
         </arguments>
       </virtualType>
    </config>
```

and run the command :

**php bin/magento setup:upgrade**

**php bin/magento static:Content:deploy**

**php bin/magento setup:di:compile**

**php bin/magento cache:flush**

working in Magento 2.4.3 version

Answer (score 0):

I also faced same issue.
After adding sequence in module.xml

```
<sequence>
    <module name="Magento_Sales" />
</sequence>
```

I upgrade the Magento.

> php bin/magento setup:upgrade

And issue is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Create di.xml at app/code/Custom/Module/etc/di.xml and add below code.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <virtualType name="Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid" type="Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Grid">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="columns" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="custom_column" xsi:type="string">sales_order.custom_column</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
</config>
```