# Add custom dynamic column in sales order grid Magento 2

Tags: magento2, grid, order-grid, dynamic-rows

This [solution](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/134890/48564) shows how to add a custom column to the sales order grid, but to add a custom column you need to add the column via XML, the problem is i need to read data collection to get available column data and add it as a custom column in sales order grid, in conclusion, I want to add multiple columns which will be generated dynamically from database collection data, is there any way to do this?

Comment: If you want to add column you have to add column using XML and also you need to add that in datasource.

Comment: @idham-choudry ,  did you find any solution of the problem?

Comment: //Useful
/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Ui/Component/Listing/Columns.php
/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/adminhtml/ui_component/product_listing.xml

Comment: did you find any solution for the problem? –@Vishal

Answer (score 2):

I have a solution that consists in taking over both columns and dataprovider for sales grid.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <dataSource name="sales_order_grid_data_source">
        <dataProvider class="Mbs\SalesGrid\Ui\Component\Listing\DataProvider" name="sales_order_grid_data_source" />
    </dataSource>
    <columns name="sales_order_columns" class="Mbs\SalesGrid\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns" />
</listing>
```

**data provider below:**

```
  class DataProvider extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider
    {
        public function __construct(
            $name,
            $primaryFieldName,
            $requestFieldName,
            ReportingInterface $reporting,
            SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder,
            RequestInterface $request,
            FilterBuilder $filterBuilder,
            array $meta = [],
            array $data = []
        ) {
            parent::__construct($name, $primaryFieldName, $requestFieldName, $reporting, $searchCriteriaBuilder, $request, $filterBuilder, $meta, $data);
        }
    
        public function getData()
        {
            $data = parent::getData();
    
            foreach ($data['items'] as &$item) {
                $item['sales_day_created'] = $this->extraDayFromDate($item['created_at']);
                $item['sales_time_created'] = $this->extraTimeFromDate($item['created_at']);
            }
    
            return $data;
        }
}


**columns below:**

 class Columns extends \Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns
    {
        /**
         * @var CustomColumnCreator
         */
        private $columnCreator;
    
        public function __construct(
            ContextInterface $context,
            CustomColumnCreator $columnCreator,
            array $components = [],
            array $data = []
        ) {
            parent::__construct($context, $components, $data);
            $this->columnCreator = $columnCreator;
        }
    
        public function prepare()
        {
            if (isset($this->components['created_at'])) {
                $billingNameColumn = $this->components['billing_name'];
    
                $column = $this->columnCreator->addColumnFromExistingColumn(
                    $billingNameColumn,
                    'sales_day_created',
                    'Sales Day',
                    11
                );
                $this->addComponent('sales_day_created', $column);
    
                $column = $this->columnCreator->addColumnFromExistingColumn(
                    $billingNameColumn,
                    'sales_time_created',
                    'Sales Time',
                    11
                );
                $this->addComponent('sales_time_created', $column);
            }
    
            parent::prepare();
        }
```

I did not put all the details as it is pretty much about parsing and I can add the full module if you need.

UPDATE: the customColumnCreator is responsible to create a column in the grid dynamically. It takes an existing column and does use its configuration to generate the new column. This is a convenient way to clone a column when we are happy about its basic configuration.

full code: https://bitbucket.org/magstaging/salesgrid/src/master/

Comment: Not sure I understand, is it a question?

Comment: In Columns.php  i don't understand what is `CustomColumnCreator`  can  you please explain @Herve Tribouilloy

Comment: I have updated my answer with explanations

Comment: ya I have a collection if I just use the collection instead of  `CustomColumnCreator`  if  I m wright

Comment: I suggest paste all your code or module and then I can comment but the collection and the column creator are 2 different things

Comment: Wait, i will post and update you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115157/discussion-between-divya-sekar-and-herve-tribouilloy).

Comment: I just create a custom collection and admin form in my module, i need to read data collection( order_column custom table) to get available column data(column_name) and add it as a custom column in sales order grid

Comment: Can you please share me  your full module for reference @Herve Tribouilloy

Comment: https://bitbucket.org/magstaging/salesgrid/src/master/

Comment: Thank you @Herve Tribouilloy, let me refer and update you.

Comment: np, sorry for the delay, i was confused who was asking.. thanks

Comment: I m  searching for more than one day thanks It's working what am expected @Herve Tribouillory

Comment: Great to feel useful, thanks for your feedback, well appreciated

Comment: Is there any way to show a image in order grid cells in custom column https://nimb.ws/mt259L

Comment: Yes, there is @divyasekar, change editotype, if you put a question, I can come down with details

Comment: Can you please help me to resolve an issue https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/325024/in-magento-2-how-to-show-an-image-in-the-custom-column-on-sales-order-grid/   @Herve Tribouilloy

Comment: I posted a question, here a link is https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/325024/in-magento-2-how-to-show-an-image-in-the-custom-column-on-sales-order-grid/

Comment: yep, will help tonight after work

Comment: ok thank you  @Herve Tribouilloy

Answer (score 1):

Make new sales_order_grid.xml file in `app/code/YourVendor/YourModule/view/adminhtml/ui_component/` and try to do there something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <columns name="sales_order_columns">
        <column name="your_column" class="YourVendor\YourModule\Ui\Component\YourColumn">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

That `class` property inside column tag allows you to write your very own renderer that will take care of the custom column. You can do it simply like that:

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace YourVendor\YourModule\Ui\Component;

use Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column;

class YourColumn extends Column
{
    /**
     * @param array $dataSource
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource): array
    {
        parent::prepareDataSource($dataSource);

        if (!isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
            return $dataSource;
        }

/* 
In this method the `$dataSource` array contains informations from order grid. 
To access your dynamic field name you don't need to refer to the xml file, 
you can just simply use $this->getData('name') to obtain the name of your renderer column.
*/
        foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as & $item) {
            //for example:
            $item[$this->getData('name')] = 'HelloWorld'; //will display the "HelloWorld" string at every row of your custom column

            $item[$this->getData('name')] = $item['increment_id'];//will display increment_id value at every row of your custom column

            //you can also perform simple operations, for example:
            if($item['increment_id'] === '123456789'){
                $item[$this->getData('name')] = 'Increment id is fake';
            }
        }

        return $dataSource;
    }
}
```

Let me know if it's what you've wanted.

Comment: No, I want for the custom column not for custom data but  your answer will help me in future