# Generate xml file of all products fields in Magento2 programmatically

Tags: magento2

I need to Generate XML file of all products fields in Magento2 programmatically.

How it possible? please advise

Comment: you can follow on that https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/182827/generate-xml-file-programmatically 
I think it is similar to your question.