# In Magento 2 how to show an image in the custom column on sales order grid

Tags: magento2, order-grid

In Magento 2 how to show an image in the custom column on the sales order grid. I added a custom dynamic column in sales order grid Magento 2

[image]

> Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\DataProvider.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing;

use Magento\Framework\Api\FilterBuilder;
use Magento\Framework\Api\Search\ReportingInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Api\Search\SearchCriteria;
use Magento\Framework\Api\Search\SearchCriteriaBuilder;
use Magento\Framework\Api\Search\SearchResultInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;

class DataProvider extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider
{
    const IMAGE_HEIGHT = '25';
    const IMAGE_STYLE = 'display: block;';
    public function __construct(
        $name,
        $primaryFieldName,
        $requestFieldName,
        ReportingInterface $reporting,
        SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder,
        RequestInterface $request,
        FilterBuilder $filterBuilder,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository,
        array $meta = [],
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($name, $primaryFieldName, $requestFieldName, $reporting, $searchCriteriaBuilder, $request, $filterBuilder, $meta, $data);
        $this->orderRepository = $orderRepository;
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
    }   
    public function getData()
    {
        $height =  self::IMAGE_HEIGHT;
        $style =  self::IMAGE_STYLE;
        $data = parent::getData();
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $collectionFlag = $objectManager->create('Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Orderflag\Collection');
        foreach ($data['items'] as &$item) {
        $collection = $objectManager->create('Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Ordercolumn\Collection')
        ->addFieldToSelect(array('column_id','column_name'));
            if($collection->getSize()){
                foreach( $collection  as $column){
                     foreach($collectionFlag  as $flagValue) {
                     $srcImage = $this->_storeManager->getStore()
                        ->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA) .$flagValue->getData('image_icon');
                    $image = sprintf("<img src='".$srcImage."' height='".$height."'>");    
                     if($column->getData('column_id') == $flagValue->getData('column_name')):
                      
                         $item[$column->getData('column_id')] =  $image;  
                            //echo $item[$column->getData('column_id')]; 
                    else:
                         $item[$column->getData('column_id')]=  'N/A';
                    endif;                   
                    }
                }
            }          
        }      
        return $data;
    }
}
```

> sales_order_grid.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <dataSource name="sales_order_grid_data_source">
        <dataProvider class="Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\DataProvider" name="sales_order_grid_data_source" />
    </dataSource>
    <columns name="sales_order_columns" class="Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns" />  
</listing>
```

> Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
use Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\CustomColumnCreator;

class Columns extends \Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns
{
    /**
     * @var CustomColumnCreator
     */
    private $columnCreator;

    public function __construct(
        ContextInterface $context,
        CustomColumnCreator $columnCreator,
        array $components = [],
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $components, $data);
        $this->columnCreator = $columnCreator;
    }

    public function prepare()
    {
        
            $billingNameColumn = $this->components['billing_name'];
            
            $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
            $collection = $objectManager->create('Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Ordercolumn\Collection')
            ->addFieldToSelect(array('column_id','column_name'));
             if($collection->getSize()){
                 foreach ( $collection  as $flag){
                  
                   $column = $this->columnCreator->addColumnFromExistingColumn(
                    $billingNameColumn,
                    $flag->getData('column_id'),
                    $flag->getData('column_name'),
                    11
                );
                $this->addComponent($flag->getData('column_id'), $column);
                 }
             }
        parent::prepare();
    }


}
```

**I added a custom dynamic column in sales order grid Magento 2**

Reference: [Add custom dynamic column in sales order grid Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/182813/add-custom-dynamic-column-in-sales-order-grid-magento-2/)

Comment: using ui component ??

Comment: Can you please refer my updated post

Comment: Did you get solution?

Comment: No, i didn't get any answer

Comment: Make sure you have set placeholder image in configuration to display when you have no image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the class `\Mbs\SalesGrid\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\CustomColumnCreator,` you need to look for the function `addColumnFromExistingColumn`

then, change this function from

```
public function addColumnFromExistingColumn(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentInterface $existingColumn,
        $columnName,
        $label,
        $sortOrder
    ) {
        $config = $existingColumn->getConfiguration();
        $config['label'] = $label;

        $arguments = [
            'data' => [
                'config' => $config,
                'sortOrder' => $sortOrder
            ],
            'context' => $existingColumn->getContext(),
        ];

        return $this->componentFactory->create($columnName, 'column', $arguments);
    }
```

to

```
 public function addColumnFromExistingColumn(
            \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentInterface $existingColumn,
            $columnName,
            $label,
            $sortOrder
        ) {
            $config = $existingColumn->getConfiguration();
            $config['label'] = $label;
            $config['bodyTmpl'] = 'ui/grid/cells/html';
    
            $arguments = [
                'data' => [
                    'config' => $config,
                    'sortOrder' => $sortOrder
                ],
                'context' => $existingColumn->getContext(),
            ];
    
            return $this->componentFactory->create($columnName, 'column', $arguments);
        }
```

If you use this function on several columns, do let me know and I can adjust something more subtil. Good luck

Comment: Thank you so much it's working  @Herve Tribouilloy

Comment: Amazing, thanks @divyasekar, good day to you

Answer (score 1):

**sales_order_grid.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <columns name="sales_order_columns">
        <column name="imagedata" class="Vendorename\ModuleName\Ui\Component\ImageData">
           <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
               <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                 <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/thumbnail</item>
                 <item name="sortable" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                 <item name="altField" xsi:type="string">store image</item>
                 <item name="has_preview" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                  <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                  <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Image</item>
                  <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">80</item>
               </item>
           </argument>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

**app/code/Vendorename/Modulename/Ui/Component/**

**ImageData.php**

```
<?php

declare (strict_types = 1);

namespace Vendorename\Modulename\Ui\Component;

use Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column;

class ImageData extends Column
{
    /**
     * @param array $dataSource
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource): array
    {
        parent::prepareDataSource($dataSource);

        if (!isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
            return $dataSource;
        }
        foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as &$item) {
            $item[$this->getData('name') . '_src'] = "https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/watch.png";
            $item[$this->getData('name') . '_alt'] = "Image name";
            $item[$this->getData('name') . '_orig_src'] = "https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/watch.png";
        }

        return $dataSource;
    }
}
```

[image]

***I Hope This Helps You.***

Comment: Can you please refer  the updated question

Comment: Please check and update me.

Comment: I will check and update you

Comment: I tried your code but it shows an error https://prnt.sc/v5rvz9

Comment: update in sales_order_grid.xml. please add filed img into sales_order table by UpgradeSchema.php

Comment: I have not created a static custom column in order gird  i created a dynamic custom column in order grid  by using this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/182813/add-custom-dynamic-column-in-sales-order-grid-magento-2/

Comment: have you added this column in sales_order table ? like this https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/92942/82670

Comment: No, I don't create any custom column in sales_order table

Comment: so without data how to get image ? you need to store image name or image path.

Comment: i stored a image path in custom table and I get a image  path in order_grid https://prnt.sc/v5wzgv

Comment: please check updated answer and update me. change in Thumbnail.php file.

Comment: I will check and update you @Msquare, sorry for the delay.

Comment: I tried your solution it shows me an issue like https://prnt.sc/v7m5ia

Comment: @divyasekar Please check my update answer. it's working perfectly. please try and update me. before check please run upgrade command

Comment: @divyasekar have you checked ?

Comment: after upgrade, I get an issue https://prnt.sc/v7o55k

Comment: your prepare() method code does not create dynamic column. please replace my above code to show image into column.

Answer (score 1):

Follow this below steps :

Create **sales_order_grid.xml** file at **app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/** and add this below code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <columns name="sales_order_columns">       
        <column name="logo" class="Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Logo">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/thumbnail</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Logo</item>
                    <item name="altField" xsi:type="string">title</item>
                    <item name="has_preview" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">30</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

Create **Logo.php** file at **app/code/Vendor/Module/Ui/Component/** and add this below code :

```
<?php

declare (strict_types = 1);

namespace Vendor\Module\Ui\Component;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column;

class Logo extends Column
{
    const ALT_FIELD = 'title';

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $storeManager;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image
     */
    protected $imageHelper;

    /**
     * @param ContextInterface              $context
     * @param UiComponentFactory            $uiComponentFactory
     * @param StoreManagerInterface         $storeManager
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image $imageHelper
     * @param array                         $components
     * @param array                         $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        ContextInterface $context,
        UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image $imageHelper,
        array $components = [],
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->imageHelper = $imageHelper;
        parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
    }

    /**
     * @param array $dataSource
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource): array
    {
        parent::prepareDataSource($dataSource);

        if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
            $fieldName = $this->getData('name');
            foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as &$item) {
                $url = '';
                if (isset($item[$fieldName])) {
                    if ($item[$fieldName] != '') {
                        $url = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(
                            \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA
                        ) . "catalog/product/custom" . $item[$fieldName];
                    } else {
                        $url = $this->imageHelper->getDefaultPlaceholderUrl('small_image');
                    }
                } else {
                    $url = $this->imageHelper->getDefaultPlaceholderUrl('small_image');
                }
                $item[$fieldName . '_src'] = $url;
                $item[$fieldName . '_alt'] = $this->getAlt($item) ?: '';
                $item[$fieldName . '_orig_src'] = $url;
            }
        }

        return $dataSource;
    }

    protected function getAlt($row)
    {
        $altField = $this->getData('config/altField') ?: self::ALT_FIELD;
        return isset($row[$altField]) ? $row[$altField] : null;
    }
}
```

Here, I used code like that if your image will not available then, placeholder image will be display.

**catalog/product/custom** => you can add your image directory here.

**Output :**

[image]

Reference : [Click Here](https://www.rohanhapani.com/how-to-display-an-image-in-the-admin-ui-grid-in-magento-2/)

Comment: I don't have a static custom column in sales_order_grid like `<column name="logo">` here my sales_order_grid.xml file https://prnt.sc/v7ma97

Comment: You can replace my xml code if you want to just add 1 single column.

Comment: If you have dynamic columns then, could you please upload Columns.php file?

Comment: I posted a Column.php  file in my question. can you please refer the above-posted question

Comment: Why you created Columns.php file? Could you please explain me?

Comment: I want to add multiple columns which will be generated dynamically from database collection data in sales_order_grid that's while I create a columns.php file  by using this reference https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/182813/add-custom-dynamic-column-in-sales-order-grid-magento-2/