# How to add Product name in magento 2.2.0

Tags: magento2.2.0

Hi guys I am trying to add columns of product name in admin order grid.

in `"maggi\vendor\magento\module-sales\Block\Adminhtml\Transactions\Detail"`

I override this function

```
 _prepareCollection(){
       $collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass())
     ->join(
        'sales/order_item',
        '`sales/order_item`.order_id=`main_table`.entity_id',
        array(
            'skus'  => new Zend_Db_Expr('group_concat(`sales/order_item`.sku SEPARATOR ",")'),
            'names' => new Zend_Db_Expr('group_concat(`sales/order_item`.name SEPARATOR ",")'),
        )
    );
     $collection->getSelect()->group('entity_id');

     $this->setCollection($collection);
     return parent::_prepareCollection();
}
```

and add column in this function

```
_prepareColumns(){
       $this->addColumn('names', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('Sales')->__('Name'),
            'width'     => '100px',
            'index'     => 'names',
            'type'        => 'text',
        ));
}
```

But nothing seems on order grid like name product name nothing.
What can I do ?

Comment: Please clear your requirement,as per my understanding you want add item name in  order grid if yes then one order may have many items so how you will manage it?

Comment: I need to add Product name in  order grid exactly, If order has more than one product so it will show all products of one order in comma separated values.

Comment: but there could be many items in single  order so how you will display all?

Comment: Comma Seperated.

Comment: you can do this by adding an extra column in grid,check link  https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/134890

Comment: Means i have to create a module for that ? And what are the queries i have to work on ?

Comment: so you are direct editing core files?

Comment: yes you are right