# Magento 2.1 : how to add profit column to admin order grid

Tags: sales-order, sales, custom-column-grid

Want to add order profit column on order grid. Any reference?

Comment: have u created custom field for this?

Comment: This one will help for you, 
 https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/134754/magento-2-how-to-add-a-new-column-to-orders-grid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find the code below, i hope you already created that profit column in `sales_order` and `sales_order_grid` table.

Namespace/Modulename/etc/di.xml

```
<virtualType name="Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid" type="Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Grid">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="columns" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="your_field" xsi:type="string">sales_order.your_field</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
</virtualType>
```

Namespace/Modulename/view/adminhtml/ui_component/sales_order_grid.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <columns name="sales_order_columns">
        <column name="your_field">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                 <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/column</item>
                </item>
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="align" xsi:type="string">left</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Your field Name</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```