# Magento 2, add new column into admin grid?

Tags: magento2.2, adminhtml, grid, custom-column-grid

Using `magento 2.2`, `admin`. `sale->order`. I want to add a new column into  `sales order grid` in backend.

[image]

Comment: Which field you want to show ?

Comment: Add new `Column` not show any exist `Column`.

Comment: I know new column but have you managed to add new field in database and it is saving when order place.

Comment: Okay. I need to add column name `driver name`  and  `diver phone number` in **grid order**, so it will need add field `dirver_name` and `driver_phone_number` into table too.

Comment: I don't understand about using table relate to `order`.

Comment: have you added those fields in `sales_order` and `sales_order_grid` tables?

Comment: No, I don't do anything with database. Because I don't understand.

Comment: Did you try the solution here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/160288/35436 or this one: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/134890/35436