# Show order comment history on invoice

Tags: sales-order, magento2.2.6

I'm trying to show the order comments history on the invoice (Magento 2.2.6)

I've written the following override:

**app/code/Denial/InvoiceComments/etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Comments" type="Denial\InvoiceComments\Block\Rewrite\Order\Comments" />
</config>
```

And

**app/code/Denial/InvoiceComments/Block/Rewrite/Order/Comments.php**

```
<?php

namespace Denial\InvoiceComments\Block\Rewrite\Order;

class Comments extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template 
{

public function getComments()

{
if ($this->_commentCollection === null) {
        $entity = $this->getEntity();
        if ($entity instanceof \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Invoice) {
            $this->_commentCollection = $this->_invoiceCollectionFactory->create();
            $this->_commentCollection = $this->_orderCollectionFactory->create();

     }
}
return $this->_commentCollection;

}

}
```

Is this right? Have I missed any steps? I ran `di:compile` but the order comments aren't showing up, only the invoice comments. Am I adding to the commentCollection correctly?

Comment: Can you explain about your issue? Are you looking for order comments to place into your invoices? But need to be sure where in admin, in invoice email or under pdf.

Comment: Sorry, I need to be able to see the order comments in admin when viewing the invoice.

Comment: What is the comment module you are using?

Comment: IWD Checkout Suite. We can see comments on the order page, but I need to see them on the invoice too. The comments are saved in the sales_order_status table in the database as normal.

Comment: @DenialDesign, Do you want to show order comment in admin invoice section ?

Comment: @DenialDesign , You have condition of instance type \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Invoice... I think you should also allow Order type as well ?

Answer (score 2):

The best approach for showing the order comments in Admin Invoice section would be to overrride the admin template file.

To override the comments template use the below code

**app/code/Denial/InvoiceComments/view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_invoice_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="order_comments">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Denial_InvoiceComments::comments/view.phtml</argument>
        </action>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
</page>
```

Copy the contents of the template file **vendor/magento-sales/view/adminhtml/templates/order/comments/view.phtml** to

**app/code/Denial/InvoiceComments/view/adminhtml/templates/comments/view.phtml**

Add the below code after line 51 just above the invoice comments section

```
<h3> Order Comments </h3>
<ul class="note-list">
<?php foreach ($_entity->getOrder()->getStatusHistoryCollection() as $status): ?>
      <?php  if ($status->getComment()): ?>
      <span class="note-list-date"><?= /* @noEscape */ $block->formatDate($status->getCreatedAt(), \IntlDateFormatter::MEDIUM) ?></span>
            <span class="note-list-time"><?= /* @noEscape */ $block->formatTime($status->getCreatedAt(), \IntlDateFormatter::MEDIUM) ?></span>
            <span class="note-list-customer">
                <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Customer') ?>
                <?php if ($status->getIsCustomerNotified()): ?>
                    <span class="note-list-customer-notified"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Notified') ?></span>
                <?php else: ?>
                    <span class="note-list-customer-not-notified"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Not Notified') ?></span>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </span>
      <div class="note-list-comment"><?= $block->escapeHtml($status->getComment(), ['b', 'br', 'strong', 'i', 'u', 'a']) ?></div>
       <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
<h3> Invoice Comments </h3>
```

The working solution output will look as shown in the screenshot link below

https://prnt.sc/lyvm9f

Comment: Thanks @mydons but it's not working for me. I've uploaded the xml file and an edited version of view.phtml to the correct folders but the invoice is still showing the default version. Do I need to run `setup:compile` or anything? I've cleared the cache and checked the logs.

Comment: Enable template path hints for adminhtml and reload the admin order view page. Check whether the template file path is showing the overrided module template or original template. Also make sure whether the order comments exists for that invoice.

Comment: it's still showing the original template @mydons Cache cleared. No errors.

Comment: @Denial Design  Have you disabled this module temporarily before. Please check if the module is still active &enabled. If it is active try deleting the contents of generated/code folder and pub/static folder and run the setup:static-content:deploy -f command

Comment: the module isn't listed at all. I have 3 files: etc/module.xml view/adminhtml/templates/order/comments/view.phtml and view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_invoice_view.xml am I missing anything?

Comment: registration.php file is missing. Once you add this file your module will be listed.

Comment: many thanks. The registration.php file was indeed missing and the `sales_order_invoice_view.xml` code was missing an end `</page>` element. All working now.

Comment: Hi @mydons  is that possible to make visible in sales_order_grid ??

Comment: We can show either one of the order or invoice comment in sales order grid, since both columns have same name i.e comment.  Refer the below link for reference                     https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/134754/magento-2-how-to-add-a-new-column-to-orders-grid

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    
    namespace Rcc\ExtraFixes\Ui\Component\Listing\Column;
    
    use \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface;
    use Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column;
    use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory;
    use Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder;
    
    
    class OrderComment extends Column {
        protected $_orderRepository;
        protected $_searchCriteria;
    
    
        public function __construct(
            ContextInterface $context,
            UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory,
            OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository,
            SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteria,
            array $components = [],
            array $data = []
        ) {
            $this->_orderRepository = $orderRepository;
            $this->_searchCriteria = $searchCriteria;
             parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
        }
    
        public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
        {
            if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
                foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as & $item) {
    
                    $order = $this->_orderRepository->get($item["entity_id"]);
                    $statusHistoryItem = $order->getStatusHistoryCollection()->getFirstItem();
                    $comment = $statusHistoryItem->getComment();
                    $item[$this->getData('name')] = $comment;
                     
                }
            }
    
            return $dataSource;
        }
    }

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <columns name="sales_order_columns">
        <column name="comment" class="Vemdpr\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\OrderComment">
            <settings>
                <label translate="true">Last Order Comment</label>
                <visible>true</visible>
            </settings>
        </column>
    </columns>

</listing>
```