# Magento 2 - Render a custom column in orders table

Tags: magento2, grid

After using [this answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/134754/magento-2-how-to-add-a-new-column-to-orders-grid#134890) from three years ago. I would like to do the same thing but with HTML.

(Only difference is, I have the configuration as an option to one of the products, rather than having the custom database column)

My sales_order_grid.xml looks like this

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <columns name="sales_order_columns">
        <column name="project_configuration" class="Wendrich\W360addtocart\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Configuration">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Project configuration</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

Currently my output looks like this:

[image]

But I want it to look like this:

[image]

Is there a function I can use to tell the formatter "This string is safe, do not escape it" like the HTMLString class in Laravel for example?

do I need to create a custom template and render it manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try adding body template for cell
**`<item name="bodyTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/cells/html</item>`**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <columns name="sales_order_columns">
        <column name="project_configuration" class="Wendrich\W360addtocart\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Configuration">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="bodyTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/cells/html</item>
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Project configuration</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

Comment: Thank you! that works fine :)