# Add custom product's attributes to products grid in magento 2

Tags: magento2

I have added custom attributes for products and used the following code to show them in the products grid.

```
/Namespace/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/product_listing.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd"> 
<columns name="product_columns" class="Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns"> 
    <column name="plenty_item_id" sortOrder="11">
        <settings>
            <filter>textRange</filter>
            <label translate="true">Plenty Item Id</label>
            <sortable>false</sortable>
        </settings>
    </column>
    <column name="plenty_item_variation_id" sortOrder="12">
        <settings>
            <filter>textRange</filter>
            <label translate="true">Plenty Variation Id</label>
            <sortable>false</sortable>
        </settings>
    </column>
</columns>
```

[image]

Fields are showing in the grid but now I need to add values. I followed some tutorials like the below one.

```
https://inchoo.net/magento-2/add-custom-columns-magento-2-products-grid/
```

After going through the tutorial I think there can  be other way as I have added a custom field to orders grid by following this link

```
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/134754/magento-2-how-to-add-a-new-column-to-orders-grid
```

So I was thinking If I can add the values to products grid using the method I used for order or do I need to follow the same link that I have provided. Someone can advise the right way of doing it or any link that I can follow to achieve this.

Comment: Have you got the solution?

Comment: @aravind not yet