# How to show the column from sales_order in the sales grid admin Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2.3, uicomponent, admin-panel, order-grid

I want to show the column and it's data from sales_order in the sales order admin panel magneto. How to show this.

Comment: have u check https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/134754/magento-2-how-to-add-a-new-column-to-orders-grid

Answer (score 0):

First I have created a UI component sales_order_grid.xml under Solwin/Module1/view/adminhtml/ui_component/sales_order_grid.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <columns name="sales_order_columns">
        <column name="extra_field" class="Solwin\Module1\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\ExtraField">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Extra Field</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

Then created the UI class under Solwin/Module1/Ui/Component/Listing/Column/ExtraField.php

```
<?php namespace Solwin\Module1\Ui\Component\Listing\Column;

use \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface;
use \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
use \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory;
use \Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column;
use \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder;

class ExtraField extends Column
{
    protected $_orderRepository;
    protected $_searchCriteria;

    public function __construct(ContextInterface $context, UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory, OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository, SearchCriteriaBuilder $criteria, array $components = [], array $data = [])
    {
        $this->_orderRepository = $orderRepository;
        $this->_searchCriteria  = $criteria;
        parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
    }

    public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
    {
        if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
            foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as & $item) {

                $order  = $this->_orderRepository->get($item["entity_id"]);
                $extra_field = $order->getData("extra_field");
                $item[$this->getData('name')] = $extra_field;
            }
        }

        return $dataSource;
    }
}
```