# How to extend core UI Component in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, xml, uicomponent, extend

I've tried to bring the `Sales -> Shipments` grid into my extension. It works fine when I use this in my `layout file .xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="styles"/>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <uiComponent name="sales_order_shipment_grid"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

But there is a problem. I need to add some more columns to the grid in my extension, but I don't want those columns to appear in the `Sales -> Shipments grid`.

I've tried the solution in this link to add a new column to the grid [How to add new column to core module of admin grid in Magento2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/87012/how-to-add-new-column-to-core-module-of-admin-grid-in-magento2)

But those columns appear in both places (which I don't want to)

I think the best solution here should be some kind of mechanism to "*extends the core UI component*", but I don't know how can do this in **Magento 2**.

How can I do this?

Thank you.

Comment: I have this exact issue. Did you find a solution (3 years ago...!)?

Comment: @Geat: sorry, I haven't worked with Magento for a long time. I can't remember if I solved this problem then :)

Comment: You're very lucky!

Comment: @Geat : one of the best things in my life is that I left using Magento, once and forever, lol